# emulador glClear:416 GL err 0x506

Tags: java, android, android-studio, emulador

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando tento executar o app no Android Studio para ver o preview de como está ficando da esse erro, já tentei usar outro emulador , até mesmo diferente do Nexus api